# Flutter: Muliple Form fields in a same row like 'Fill in the Blanks' style

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Is there any effective way to achieve like this?

[Textfields in a row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6Tm6.png)

Comment: did you face any issue with using simple row .?

Comment: you can try using the Class Row: https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Row-class.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `Row` should suffice. If you need more control over the width of child widgets, consider using `Expanded` and it's `flex` attribute.

```
Row(
  children: <Widget>[
    Expanded(
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            flex: 3,
            child: TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Time'),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 4,
            child: Text("(in mins)/"),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    Expanded(
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            flex: 3,
            child: TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Whistle'),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 4,
            child: Text("(whistles)"),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

In the above code, the first row contains two Expanded with no flex, which means both widget will have the same width.

The inside row contains two Expanded: one with flex factor of 3 and one with flex of 4, and the first widget's (TextField) length will be 3/7 of the total row width, while the Text's width will be 4/7.